# Check if a dollar value exists in a string with exception using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if an input string contains dollar($) symbol with amount. If an input contains a dollar with then amount, then the input string is accepted. Else, it is not accepted. Also, the input should disregard the **$70**.

Example inputs :

```
$str1 = "I have $70 and has $50 change." // Should return true because it has dollar value $50
$str2 = "I have $70 only." //Should return FALSE. $70 is excluded.
```

This input should be queried from a database which I have in mind something like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {table} where description like '%{$str}%' "
```

I know how to use `like` in mysql. But the problem is how to extract the input so that it can check the input query and disregard the $70.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE description LIKE '%$%' AND description NOT LIKE '%$70%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LOCATE('$',description) > 0 AND LOCATE('$70',description)=0
```

This one should be a little more specific

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE description REGEXP '\$[0-9]+' AND description NOT LIKE '%$70%'
```